# Is there a concise term for a non-real complex number?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, terminology

Strictly speaking, a complex number is *any* number that can be represented in the form $z=a+bi$, even if $b=0$. This means that $5$ is technically a complex number. There are certainly advantages of this being the case: for example, the real numbers are a subset of the complex numbers. However, this makes it a little awkward to describe a polynomial that does not have real roots—if I say 'this quadratic has $2$ complex roots' then this is really true for *any* quadratic. I suppose I could say 'this quadratic has $2$ non-real roots', but this also feels a little awkward (though it may be my best option). With this in mind, is there a specific term for a *non-real* complex number?

Comment: $5$ is technically also a natural, integer, rational, irrational, real and complex number. I don't know a specific term, the way to indicate it should be $z\in\mathbb C$ with $\Im(z)\neq 0$.

Comment: @Its_me Imaginary means it's of the form $0 + bi$, I think the OP wants any complex number that's not real.

Comment: Non-real is the right term.

Comment: @JairTaylor Yes, that's right. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: Just say that the roots have non-zero imaginary components

Comment: "this quadratic has 2 non-real roots" is not awkward at all, that's perfectly fine.